# Arduino fade to color change

Tags: arduino-uno

I am making a fun LED Christmas tree project using this code:

```
// Source location \\adam\U_DRIVE\_BACKED_UP\_Documents\Electronics\XmasTree
#include <FastLED.h>
#define NUM_LEDS 102
#define DATA_PIN 6
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Boot");
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

  //  SetRandomLight;
  SetAllOff();
  delay(10); //Delay before getting going.
  BootUp();
  randomSeed(analogRead(0) + analogRead(1) + analogRead(2) + analogRead(3) + analogRead(4) + analogRead(5) + analogRead(6));
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  SingleDrift();
  FastLED.show();
  //delay(random(50));
}

void FadeAll(int x)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    leds[i].subtractFromRGB(x);
  }
}

void SetRandomLight() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    leds[i].r = random(128);
    leds[i].g = random(128);
    leds[i].b = random(128);
    Serial.println(i);
  }
}

void SetAllOff()
{
  Serial.println("Blanking all.");
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    leds[i] = 0x000000;
    leds[i].r = 0;
    leds[i].g = 0;
    leds[i].b = 0;

    //Serial.println(i);
  }
  FastLED.show();
}

void SingleDrift() {
  int mini = 5;
  int maxi = 255;
  FastLED.setBrightness(maxi);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    if (leds[i].r > 64) leds[i].r = leds[i].r - 8;
    if (leds[i].g > 64) leds[i].g = leds[i].g - 8;
    if (leds[i].b > 64) leds[i].b = leds[i].b - 8;

    int rnd = random(10);
    if (rnd == 1 && leds[i].r >= 2) leds[i].r = leds[i].r - 1;
    if (rnd == 2 && leds[i].g >= 2) leds[i].g = leds[i].g - 1;
    if (rnd == 3 && leds[i].b >= 2) leds[i].b = leds[i].b - 1;
    if (rnd == 4) leds[i].fadeToBlackBy(2);
    if (rnd == 5) leds[i].g++;
    //if (rnd == 6 && leds[i].g < 240) leds[i].g = leds[i].g + 1;
    //if (rnd == 7 && leds[i].b < 240) leds[i].b = leds[i].b + 1;
    if (leds[i].g < 2) leds[i].g = 2;
  }

  int i = random(NUM_LEDS);
  Serial.println(i);
  if (leds[i].r + leds[i].g + leds[i].b > 10) return; //If the LED is still bright, do not change it.
  if (random(100) > 80)
  {
    //Choose a colour
    int r = random(20);
    switch (r)
    {
      case 99:
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
        {
          int x = leds[i].r;
          leds[i].r = leds[i].b;
          leds[i].b = x;
        }

      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
        leds[i] = CRGB::Red;
        break;
      case 4:
      case 5:
      case 6:
        leds[i] = CRGB::Green;
        break;
      case 7:
        leds[i] = CRGB::Blue;
        break;
      case 8:
        leds[i].r = random(128, 255);
        leds[i].g = random(128, 255);
        leds[i].b = random(128, 255);
      case 9:
        leds[i] = CRGB::Yellow;
        break;
      case 10:
        leds[i] = CRGB::Crimson;
        break;
      case 12:
        leds[i] = CRGB::Aqua;
        break;
      case 13:
        leds[i] = CRGB::BlueViolet;
        break;
      case 14:
        leds[i] = CRGB::MidnightBlue;
        break;
      case 15:
        leds[i].setRGB( 255, 255, 255);
        break;
    }
  }
}

void BootUp()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    leds[i].b = map(i, 0, NUM_LEDS, 0, 255);
    leds[i].r = map(i, NUM_LEDS, 0, 0, 255);
  }
  for (int pc = 0; pc < 100; pc++)
  {
    FastLED.setBrightness(pc);
    FastLED.show();
    delay(3);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    leds[i] = -leds[i];
    FastLED.show();
    delay(10);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    leds[i].setRGB( 0, 10, 0);

    FastLED.show();
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

The LED cycle currently fades to green every time, so I would like to add different color fades. However, I could not figure out how to change the color/timing after poking around. Could someone please point me in the right direction for what I changes to the code I need to make?

Comment: why don't you look at the example code in the fastLED library? ... you should be able to find it in the example sketches in the arduino IDE

Answer (score 0):

I think line 84 that keeps the leds green instead of going black. I think line 81 is there to create some kind of shimmer effect on some of the green leds and to skew the color to a bit more green. So I removed those. To prevent the leds from going to black instead of green, I added an if statement that stops any further fading out, if the total "brightness" is `16` or lower. I have no idea how this will look. You might have to tweak this 16-value a bit.

That's the best I could do without a full rewrite of the code.

```
void SingleDrift() {
  int mini = 5;
  int maxi = 255;
  FastLED.setBrightness(maxi);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    if (leds[i].r > 64) leds[i].r = leds[i].r - 8;
    if (leds[i].g > 64) leds[i].g = leds[i].g - 8;
    if (leds[i].b > 64) leds[i].b = leds[i].b - 8;

    if ( (leds[i].r + leds[i].g + leds[i].b) > 16) // prevent fading to black
    {
      int rnd = random(10);
      if (rnd == 1 && leds[i].r >= 2) leds[i].r = leds[i].r - 1;
      if (rnd == 2 && leds[i].g >= 2) leds[i].g = leds[i].g - 1;
      if (rnd == 3 && leds[i].b >= 2) leds[i].b = leds[i].b - 1;
      if (rnd == 4) leds[i].fadeToBlackBy(2);
      //if (rnd == 5) leds[i].g++;
      //if (rnd == 6 && leds[i].g < 240) leds[i].g = leds[i].g + 1;
      //if (rnd == 7 && leds[i].b < 240) leds[i].b = leds[i].b + 1;
      //if (leds[i].g < 2) leds[i].g = 2; // I think this line kept the leds green
    }
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is a bit of a mess. It has some code that will never execute, as well as very confusing structure.

If it were me I would throw away that code and start over with code that does some other animation. You won't break anything, so play.

As to the code you posted:

It looks to me like the first for loop that cycles through all the LEDs is set to first fade all the LEDs down towards 0 brightness by 8 while their value is > 64.

After the global fade, it then uses a random number 0-9 to decide what to do next for each LED.

1. If the random value is 1, 2, or 3, it reduces the red, green, or blue channels by 1.
2. If the random value is 4, it drives the current LED to black.
3. If the random value is 5, it increases the green channel of the current LED by 1.
   finally, it sets the green channel of the current LED back to 2 if it drops below 2. **That means that every LED will end up with flicker with a dim green color unless the next section changes that LED's color to something different**.

I added "**this" comments to the lines that drive the LEDs towards green.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    if (leds[i].r > 64) leds[i].r = leds[i].r - 8;
    if (leds[i].g > 64) leds[i].g = leds[i].g - 8;
    if (leds[i].b > 64) leds[i].b = leds[i].b - 8;

    int rnd = random(10);
    if (rnd == 1 && leds[i].r >= 2) leds[i].r = leds[i].r - 1;
    if (rnd == 2 && leds[i].g >= 2) leds[i].g = leds[i].g - 1;
    if (rnd == 3 && leds[i].b >= 2) leds[i].b = leds[i].b - 1;
    if (rnd == 4) leds[i].fadeToBlackBy(2);
    if (rnd == 5) leds[i].g++;  //**This will tend to make this LED flicker green.
    //if (rnd == 6 && leds[i].g < 240) leds[i].g = leds[i].g + 1;
    //if (rnd == 7 && leds[i].b < 240) leds[i].b = leds[i].b + 1;
    if (leds[i].g < 2) leds[i].g = 2; //**This will make each LED stop at dim green.
  }
```

If you want the LEDs to end up at some color other than green, you might want to change those last lines of the first for loop You could change that first section to something like this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    if (leds[i].r > 64) leds[i].r = leds[i].r - 8;
    if (leds[i].g > 64) leds[i].g = leds[i].g - 8;
    if (leds[i].b > 64) leds[i].b = leds[i].b - 8;

    int rnd = random(11);
    if (rnd == 1 && leds[i].r >= 2) leds[i].r = leds[i].r - 1;
    if (rnd == 2 && leds[i].g >= 2) leds[i].g = leds[i].g - 1;
    if (rnd == 3 && leds[i].b >= 2) leds[i].b = leds[i].b - 1;
    if (rnd == 4) leds[i].fadeToBlackBy(2);

    if (rnd == 5) leds[i].g++;  //**This will tend to make this LED flicker green.
    if (rnd == 6) leds[i].r++;  //**This will tend to make this LED flicker red.
    if (rnd == 7) leds[i].b++;  //**This will tend to make this LED flicker blue.

    if (rnd == 8) && (leds[i].g < 2) leds[i].g = 2; //**This will make the LED go dim green
    if (rnd == 9) && (leds[i].r < 2) leds[i].r = 2; //**This will make the LED go dim red
    if (rnd == 10) && (leds[i].b < 2) leds[i].b = 2; //**This will make the LED go dim blue
  }
```

Then it picks one random LED, and 20% of the time, does more random stuff to the color of that LED if it is dim enough. It uses a random value from 0-19 to decide what to do in the next switch statement. The first case is `case 99:`, which can never execute because the random value will never be greater than 19. For other values, it forces that LED to be a bright primary color, or maybe white, or maybe a color with random RGB values ranging from 128 to 255.